# "Subclass" a Riot.js template/custom element?

Tags: riot.js

With Riot.js, is there any provision for inheritance with custom elements?

As a trivial example, suppose I have a custom element `<custom-button>`.  Something like this:

```
<custom-button>
  <button>{innerContent}</button>
</custom-button>
```

Now, maybe I want to sub-class this button as a new custom element, perhaps something that includes an icon:

```
<custom-button-with-icon>
  <inner-content>
    {icon} {text}
  </inner-content>
  <script>
    this.extends('custom-button');
  </script>
</custom-button-with-icon>
```

Is there anything like this in Riot.js that allows me to override part of an outer template, or otherwise subclass a custom element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Riot.js v4, for subclassing the template/custom component you can use the slot functionality of Riot.js. You create the component with a slot field

```html
<custom-button>
  <button>
   <slot/>
  </button>
</custom-button>
```

Then you can create another component which uses the custom button

```html
<custom-button-with-icon>
  <custom-button>
    {icon} {text}
  </custom-button>
</custom-button-with-icon>
```

Then the slot would be replaced with `{icon} {text}` when the custom-button-with-icon component is used. 
More info here: https://riot.js.org/api/#slots

Comment: Thanks, is there any way for slot to be defined in `custom-button`, later to be overridden by `custom-button-with-icon`?